# background-color não funciona quando é usado em "classList.toggle()"

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

HTML:

```
<div class="barraLateral" id="barraLateral">
    <ul class="menuVertical" id="menuVertical">             
        <li name="liCat" onclick="darkTheme()"><i class="mdi mdi-theme-light-dark mdi-24px"></i><a name="cat">Dark Theme</a></li>
        <li name="liCat" onclick="deslogar()"><i class="mdi mdi-close-circle-outline mdi-24px"></i><a name="cat">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function darkTheme() {
    document.getElementById("corpoPagina").classList.toggle('bodyDark');
    var liCat = document.getElementsByName("liCat");
    for (var i = 0; i <= liCat.length; i++) 
    {
        liCat[i].classList.toggle('menuDark');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.menuDark {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Quando o usuario clica no botão pra virar DarkTheme, o `body` muda a cor de fundo e o menu era pra mudar também, porém só muda a borda do menu.

Em outras palavras: Ao executar a função darkTheme, o atributo `border: 1px solid red` é executado já o atributo `background-color: red` não é executado.

Comment: Para que está usando esse loop `for`?

Comment: inclua o html em sua pergunta.

Comment: O `for` é usado para colocar nova classe em todos os itens da `<li>`, vai percorrendo e acrescentando. Essas `<li>` podem aumentar a quantidade conforme o usuario for inserindo novas categorias, por isso o `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no `for`, quando o correto seria usar `i < liCat.length` e não:

```
i <= liCat.length
```

Ao percorrer array, usa-se apenas o operador *menor que* `<`, caso contrário a variável `i` terá valor maior que o número de itens na array retornando erro.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração e infelizmente continuou não funcionando. A nova classe é adicionada, porém só o atributo `border` que é aplicado aos elementos. =(

Comment: Coloque na frente do background o `!important` e faça um teste, assim: `background-color: red !important;`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado dvd, você é fera!